# Can I have multiple Hubots on slack

Tags: hubot

I am working with a group of programmers.  We all want a raspberry running hubot with special abilities.  Slack only issues ONE api key.  If we have multiple raspberry pies connected would we use the same api key? Or will slack only allow one hubot to connect?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use: https://my.slack.com/services/new/hubot

This will create another hubot integration within your slack. Therefore you can have multiple bots with different nicknames, etc. running in whatever channels.

ie. My slack setup currently has 2 separate hubot integration running.

Answer (score 0):

> would we use the same api key?

Yes.

By accident I already had multiple hubots (from the actual server and my dev machine) being connected to the same Slack api key and it worked as you asked.

Comment: I agree to @jcook solution. By this way, your two hubots have same name, if you send command to them, they will all begin to work, I don't want that, I want the two hubots have two difference names, so I can know which one should work.